# C# How to insert multiple rows in database with primary key

Tags: c#, database

Once a month I get an xml file with customers billings for the last month. I need to store this information in a database. I have a table named `transactions`. My primary key is the `customers_nr`. Currently when I'm inserting data, I'm getting error

> violoation to primary key......

I'm using a table adapter for inserting. Basically I only need to keep filling the database with information. So is there any command for handling this? Or how should I do

Example of informaton

```
customer_nr: 12345
Billing_name: Microsoft
Billing_city: Seattle
Billing_amount 300
Billing_name: Mcdonalds
Billing_city: Seattle
Billing_amount 25

customer_nr: 4321
Billing_name: Ikea
Billing_city: New York
Billing_amount 1200
```

Comment: So what **should** happen if you receive a new entry for a customer with a customer id that already exists?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

billing datetime i more suitable for the primary key in this relation, alt. customer_nr + billing_datetime.

If you don't have any date and time for billing, or just know the month, you could use customer_nr, year, month as a composite primary key.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that you have duplicate value for your primary key in at least two records .

remember that primary key enforces uniqueness for data inside it.

so you can not insert two records in a table with same value for primary key. you can change your primary key to a new field (for example an auto number field) so you removed uniqueness constraint from your old primary key field and then you can insert duplicates in it!

Comment: Yes i know this. How to avoid it?

Comment: you can not, the only way is to move your primary key constraint to other field.

Comment: @dumbel = change your primary key. The customers_nr (which I am guessing is an identifier for the customer) cannot by itself be a primary key of your transaction table, since you will have multiple transactions for any given customer. Do you have a transaction identifier, such as TransactionID or transaction_num? You may want to use that instead of customers_nr for your primary key. Basically, you need to find the column or combination of columns in your transaction table that are unique by row. That column(s) should be your primary key.

Comment: as JeremyDWill said, just create a new column "TransactionId" and set auto number to true. then change your primary key to new column. Transaction column should have its own primary key not customer's

Answer (score 0):

Using the customer number is then obviously not a unique value, meaning it cannot be used as a Primary Key.

Create an `IDENTITY` column, or utilize a `GUID` with `newsequentialid()` (pref. as the field default) to achieve a unique key in the table.

---

Example:

You have the database structure as follows:

- TransactionID (This is the new field, `uniqueidentifer` with `newsequentialid()` as the default value)
- Customer_Nr
- Billing_name
- Billing_city
- Billing_amount
- Billing_name
- Billing_city
- Billing_amount

You would then go as follows:

```
INSERT INTO transactions (Customer_Nr, Billing_name, Billing_city, Billing_amount)
VALUES ('12345', 'Microsoft', 'Seattle', 300);
```

As you see, you won't need to change any code with values due to the automatically generated (unique) primary key value.

---

A note regarding `newsequentialid()` is that if your data requires security / privacy, do not use `newsequentialid()`, as it is trivial to guess sequences.

Comment: If you create a new identity - please by all means use `newsequentialid()` as the default! Your index fragmentation will be much less than with the random `newid()` function

Comment: Yes! If you create a primary key (clustering key) on `uniqueidentifier` the index fragmentation will be horrible - unless you use `newsequentialid()` as default value - then it's bearable

Comment: @marc - Also worth noting that newsequentialid() is a big nono if security/privacy is a concern. If you know, how does newsequentialid() react to a crashed DB server?